# Delete ros package path

Tags: ros, ros-package-path, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can we delete the current package paths, create a new package path?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36914/delete-ros-package-path/) by [sandeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2663/sandeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

go to your home folder, on the top menu hit view, then select show hidden files. Click on the .bashrc file and scroll to the bottom and change the line:

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=WHATEVER YOU WANT

where WHATEVER YOU WANT is a valid location on your file system, multiple locations can be seperated by a ':' for example mine is

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks

---

Originally posted by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) with karma: 600 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on 2012-06-20**:
always keep /opt/ros/electric/stacks as that's where the main install is

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-07-02**:
It's also good practice to use the rosws (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosws) tool and rosinstall (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall) to maintain your package path, rather than doing it by hand.